# How can I add an onclick event to just the first column of a gridview and not the entire row?

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview, onclick, code-behind

Title is pretty self-explanatory. I have a gridview, and when the user clicks on a particular row, I add a shadow to the first column. The problem is, the user can click anywhere on the row, and the shadow is added, but the link is only opened in a new tab if the user clicks on the link (i.e. first column). How do I add the onclick event to the first column of every row only?

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Javascript function to call on row-click event
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:void SelectRow(this);");
    }
```

If it helps, I used the example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/209416/Make-the-entire-GridView-Row-clickable-and-selecta) to implement SelectRow.

Comment: `javascript:void` is useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add it to `e.Row.Cells[0]`  instead

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onClick", "SelectRow(this);");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:void SelectRow(this);");
```